# IE display problems using protoype.js

Tags: internet-explorer, prototypejs

This is a recent problem but I'm using scriptaculous on a site and this week all the IE browsers are not displaying any content. The stated error is:

```
Message: Unable to get value of the property 'replace': object is null or undefined Line: 1400 Char: 13 Code: 0
```

This is on the `prototype.js` file (version 1.5.0)

All other browsers are fine. Any ideas on how to fix it

Thanks

Comment: Can you upgrade Prototype? Newer versions have many fixes for IE.

Answer (score 0):

Post some code if this doesn't help, but that error usually means that you're trying to access a property or call a method on something that's null or undefined. Debug what you're calling `replace` on to see if it is actually a '[Prototype extended element](http://prototypejs.org/learn/extensions)' (check out the bottom comment) before the error is thrown.